# Wordpress in Containers - getting 502 when loading some images

Tags: wordpress, azure, docker

I have Wordpress deployed in Azure AppService with containers (Azure Container registry is used)
the image used is from the docker hub -> wordpress:latest
I also have --settings WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=TRUE  enabled so my files are persisted in the VM

I have noticed that images are not displayed

I see a 502 error - https://{website}.azurewebsites.net/wp-includes/images/spinner-2x.gif
I have checked with KUDU and the image is there

Could anyone point me into the right direction to fix this issue?

I have followed steps from this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app

Comment: Does it happen with all the images/Gif or just this spinner-2x.gif? 

1.Kindly add this parameter for Apache image: 
Set ‘EnableMMAP Off’ in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

2.If you haven’t done this, you can review the docker logs to fetch more details. 
https://[sitename].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logs/docker

Comment: @AjayKumar-MSFT it is happening with all images. :(

Comment: @Dorin any updates on this?  We're having the same issue.

Comment: no. It is happening only when there is a mounted volume to local machine or Azure storage. App gateway doesn't like that for some reason. I have moved to an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

I opened a support ticket with Azure who said this is a [known issue](https://azureossd.github.io/2020/09/15/unable-to-download-static-content-php-on-azure-app-service-linux/index.html).  The current workaround is to disable the following apache settings in the apache2.conf file:

```
EnableMMAP Off
EnableSendfile Off
```

If you're using Azure's base PHP image from mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/php, they've built in these apache settings in their 7.4-apache_20210422.1 version (and presumably any later versions).  See https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/appsvc/php/tags/list to list image versions.

Answer (score -1):

Setting WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=TRUE enable persistent shared storage.  You then need to use the WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME environment variable that points to /home in your folder paths and volumes.

```
${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot:/var/www/html
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux)

Comment: this is what i have in my docker-compose file:  restart: always
    volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot:/var/www/html