# Drupal in Containers - getting 502 when loading some imags(gif,jpg,png) in Azure

Tags: azure, drupal, azure-web-app-service

I hosted a drupal application in azure using the docker container. I mapped the sites volume in Azure files as well as site volume.

The site can load css and js files in the volumes without error but can't load the images and gives 502 gateway error.

Docker logs shows no error and shows the images were fetched there but while loading on page it shows 502 error.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having same issues.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65021932/wordpress-in-containers-getting-502-when-loading-some-images

I think this has the answer.

Comment: It was something to do with PHP 7.4